# Render partial after ajax call without rails helpers (using webpack)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, fetch

In the `show.html.erb` page I have a list of items:

```
<div id="shopOffersPartial">
   <%= render "shops/shop_offers", offers: @offers %>
</div>
```

In the partial, there is simply a loop. `@offers` come from the backend

```
<% offers.each do |offer| %>
  <%= render "shared/mini_offer_card/content", offer: offer, shop: @shop %>
<% end %>
```

I want to filter the element son every key up event. For that, I listen to an input. I have the JS logic in Webpack.

```
const shopFilterProductsInput = document.getElementById("shopFilterProducts");
const shopId = shopFilterProductsInput.dataset.shopid;
const shopOffersPartial = document.getElementById("shopOffersPartial");

const filterOfferes = (e) => {
  let inputValue = shopFilterProductsInput.value;

  const url = `/shops/${shopId}?query=${inputValue}`;

  fetch(url)
  .then(function() {
    shopOffersPartial.innerHTML = "<%= render 'shops/shop_offers', offers: @offers %>";
  })
  .catch(function() {
      // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
  });
}

if (shopFilterProductsInput) {
  shopFilterProductsInput.addEventListener("keyup", filterOffers)
}
```

My question is in this part of the code:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(function() {
    shopOffersPartial.innerHTML = "<%= render 'shops/shop_offers', offers: @offers %>";
  })
```

Once I get the response, I want to re-render the partial which has the list of items.

In rails, with .js.erb you can do things like that:

```
// app/views/reviews/create.js.erb
// Here you generate *JavaScript* that would be executed in the browser
function refreshForm(innerHTML) {
  const newReviewForm = document.getElementById('new_review');
  newReviewForm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}

function addReview(reviewHTML) {
  const reviews = document.getElementById('reviews');
  reviews.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', reviewHTML);
}

<% if @review.errors.any? %>
  refreshForm('<%= j render "reviews/form", restaurant: @restaurant, review: @review %>');
<% else %>
  addReview('<%= j render "reviews/show", review: @review %>');
  refreshForm('<%= j render "reviews/form", restaurant: @restaurant, review: Review.new %>');
<% end %>
```

But I am in a Webpack file. I can't use the Rails helpers.

How can I render then a Rails helper using Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
  fetch(url)
  .then(function() {
    shopOffersPartial.innerHTML = "<%= render 'shops/shop_offers', offers: @offers %>";
  })
```

should be replaced with this:

```
  fetch(url)
  .then(function(res) {
     return res.text();
  }).then(function(html) {
     shopOffersPartial.innerHTML = html;
  });
```

You don't have to use `render` in the JS file. The controller accessed by `/shops/${shopId}?query=${inputValue}` should return the needed html. Something like this:

```
def show
  # offers = ???
  # ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'shops/show' }
    format.js { return plain: render_to_string("shops/shop_offers", offers: offers, layout: false) }
  end
end
```